# Orbit view with trackpad in Blender 2.8

Tags: modeling, osx

I have been running the new Blender 2.8 beta version on a Macbook Pro 2015 and figured out that's not possible to orbit and rotate the view with trackpad gestures, even pressing `Shift` key or similar.

Does anyone know if it's possible to orbit with two fingers like Blender 2.7X? I've been looking for the solution but I didn't find anything, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you can enable to orbit with the view with the trackpad by going to `Edit`>`Preferences`>`Keymap` and switching the upper setting to `Blender 27X` template or `Blender` template.

[image: Keys templates]